# preg_replace to replace a div for a minimum width

Tags: html, regex, preg-replace

I have a user input form where the user is allowed to use HTML, such as `div`, `span`, etc.

I would like to clean the input **only** if a user happens to put in a `div` with a `style="width:"` that is over the site *width* (which in this case is 800px.)

So I wanted to do a `preg_replace` searching for `div style="width:"`
only when *width* is greater than 800px.

I already have all other fixes in place for `spans`, `div width=""`, etc. but the `preg_replace` on the `div style="width:"` where the width is only changed **if** it is greater than 800 (such as 1500px, 2000px, 801px) eludes me - I cannot get it to work.

Is there **any** way to achieve this?

Comment: `(\d{4,}|9\d{2,}|8[^0]\d|80[^0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The pony he comes...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

How would you go about handling something like `width:140%`? Or `width: 600px; margin: 200px;`? Or just an image with no defined width but an intrinsic width of over 800px?

It's far easier to just put the user-supplied content in a wrapper:

```
<div style="width: 800px; overflow: hidden;">USER CONTENT HERE</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I think I was overthinking it - the overflow:hidden didn't even cross my mind.  It is the best fix.  Thank you.